# Как понять данную запись числа?

Tags: java

В одной простенькой задачке столкнулся с такой записью числа "1е-3".Там был следующий код:

```
int a = 15;
int b = 4;
float c = a / b;
double d = a * 1e-3 + c;
```

Попробовал записать отдельно 1 переменную - `double g=1e-3;`вывел в консоль,получилось 0.001. Подскажите пожалуйста, что это за запись такая?Раньше с таким не сталкивался

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C особенно раздел "Компьютерный способ..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Запись **e-3** - Это умножение на **10 в степени -3**. В некоторых случаях такая запись может встречаться в двоичной системе счисления, тогда она будет означать умножение на 2 в степени -3 (но вряд ли вы с этим столкнётесь). Понятно, что вместо -3 может быть любое целое число. Для типа данных double степень десятки может находиться, обычно, в пределах трёх сотен (как в плюс, так и в минус). Сама буква e (или E) обычно расшифровывается как "Exponent".